# How can parsing a 17MB text file into List cause OutOfMemory with 128MB heap?

Tags: java, out-of-memory, heap-memory

In some part of my application, I am parsing a 17MB log file into a list structure - one LogEntry per line. There are approximately 100K lines/log entries, meaning approx. 170 bytes per line. What surprised me is that I run out of heap space, even when I specify 128MB (256MB seems sufficient). How can 10MB of text turned into a list of objects cause a tenfold increase in space?

I understand that String objects use at least twice the amount of space compared to ANSI text (Unicode, one char=2 bytes), but this consumes at least four times that.

**What I am looking for is an approximation for how much an ArrayList of n LogEntries will consume, or how my method might create extraneous objects that aggravate the situation**  (see comment below on `String.trim()`)

This is the data part of my LogEntry class

```
public class LogEntry { 
    private Long   id; 
    private String system, version, environment, hostName, userId, clientIP, wsdlName, methodName;
    private Date                timestamp;
    private Long                milliSeconds;
    private Map<String, String> otherProperties;
```

This is the part doing the reading

```
public List<LogEntry> readLogEntriesFromFile(File f) throws LogImporterException {
    CSVReader reader;
    final String ISO_8601_DATE_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS";

    List<LogEntry> logEntries = new ArrayList<LogEntry>();
    String[] tmp;
    try {
        int lineNumber = 0;
        final char DELIM = ';';
        reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f)), DELIM);
        while ((tmp = reader.readNext()) != null) {
            lineNumber++;

            if (tmp.length < LogEntry.getRequiredNumberOfAttributes()) {

                String tmpString = concat(tmp);

                if (tmpString.trim().isEmpty()) {
                    logger.debug("Empty string");
                } else {
                    logger.error(String.format(
                            "Invalid log format in %s:L%s. Not enough attributes (%d/%d). Was %s . Continuing ...",
                            f.getAbsolutePath(), lineNumber, tmp.length, LogEntry.getRequiredNumberOfAttributes(), tmpString)
                    );
                }

                continue;
            }

            List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(tmp));
            String system, version, environment, hostName, userId, wsdlName, methodName;
            Date timestamp;
            Long milliSeconds;
            Map<String, String> otherProperties;

            system = values.remove(0);
            version = values.remove(0);
            environment = values.remove(0);
            hostName = values.remove(0);
            userId = values.remove(0);
            String clientIP = values.remove(0);
            wsdlName = cleanLogString(values.remove(0));
            methodName = cleanLogString(stripNormalPrefixes(values.remove(0)));
            timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat(ISO_8601_DATE_PATTERN).parse(values.remove(0));
            milliSeconds = Long.parseLong(values.remove(0));

            /* remaining properties are the key-value pairs */
            otherProperties = parseOtherProperties(values);

            logEntries.add(new LogEntry(system, version, environment, hostName, userId, clientIP,
                    wsdlName, methodName, timestamp, milliSeconds, otherProperties));
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new LogImporterException("Error reading log file: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new LogImporterException("Error parsing logfile: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    return logEntries;
}
```

Utility function used for populating the map

```
private Map<String, String> parseOtherProperties(List<String> values) throws ParseException {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    String[] tmp;
    for (String s : values) {
        if (s.trim().isEmpty()) {
            continue;
        }

        tmp = s.split(":");
        if (tmp.length != 2) {
            throw new ParseException("Could not split string into key:value :\"" + s + "\"", s.length());
        }
        map.put(tmp[0], tmp[1]);
    }
    return map;
}
```

Comment: I am not a Java expert but maybe `new ArrayList` inside the loop creates too much memory pressure for the GC to handle, can you move it outside the loop?

Comment: I can see that creating an ArrayList inside of a loop might be a bit ineffective, and cause more work for the GC, but that should not mean I should run out of heap space. Too much for for the GC actually has a specific Exception in Java, and I have seen that in other scenarios :)

Comment: Of course, I can move the new ArrayList out of the loop, and reuse it by list.clear(), but I don't think that adds much to the issue here.

Comment: `tmpString.trim()` in a loop may be creating copies of string? [javadoc] http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim(). Similarly `String.format()` may also be creating copies?

Comment: @Bimalesh Jha Hmm ... interesting!

Comment: 8 Strings (no date) = 64B,
2 Longs = 16B,
1 Date (a Long?) = Object + Long = 16B,
Map with 2*2*10 chars = 160B (see comment on Ingo's answer).
That should total 256B. In addition comes the string content, say 90 chars = 180 byte. Perhaps a byte or two in each end of the list item when put in the list, so in total somewhere around 450 byte per log line.

Calculations based on info from http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/object_memory_usage.shtml and discussion under Ingo's answer

Comment: Per Ingo, the longs are actually Longs (Objects) consuming 8 Bytes for the Object bit alone, so probably consuming 16 byte per Long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have a Map there, where you store other properties. Your code doesn't show how this Map is populated, but keep in mind that Maps may have a hefty memory overhead compared to the memory needed for the entries themselves.

The size of the array that backs the Map (at least 16 entries * 4 bytes) + one key/value pair per entry + the size of data themselves. Two map entries, each using 10 chars for key and 10 chars for value, would consume 16*4 + 2*2*4 + 2*10*2 + 2*10*2 + 2*2*8= 64+16+40+40+24 = 184 bytes (1 char = 2 byte, a String object consumes min 8 byte). That alone would almost double the space requirements for the entire log string.

Add to this that the LogEntry contains 12 Objects, i.e. at least 96 bytes. Hence the log objects alone would need around 100 bytes, give or take some, without the Map and without actual string data. Plus all the pointers for the references (4B each). I count at least 18 with the Map, meaning 72 bytes.

Adding the data (-object references and object "headers" mentioned in the last paragraph):
2 longs = 16B, 1 date stored as long = 8B, the map = 184B. In addition comes the string content, say 90 chars = 180 byte. Perhaps a byte or two in each end of the list item when put in the list, so in total somewhere around 100+72+16+8+184+180=560 ~ 600 byte per log line.

So around 600 byte per log line, meaning 100K lines would consume around 60MB minimum. This would place it at least in the same order of magnitude as the heap size that was set asize. In addition comes the fact that [tmpString.trim() in a loop might be creating copies of string](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29). Similarly String.format() may also be creating copies. The rest of the application must also fit within this heap space, and might explain where the rest of memory is going.

Comment: Code added for parseOtherProperties(). Could you perhaps supply me with some numbers for what this object might amount to in bytes?

Comment: The size of the array that backs the Map (at least 16 entries * 4 bytes) + one key/value pair per entry + the size of data themselves.

Comment: You can easily test if it works without the map, by not populating it in a test run.

Comment: Interesting. Two map entries of 2*2*10 chars  (10 bytes for key, 10 for value) would consume 16*4 + 2*2*4 + 2*10*2 + 2*10*2 = 64+16+40+40 = 160 bytes (1 char = 2 byte)! That alone would almost triple the space requirements for the entire log string.

Comment: Add to this that your LogEntry contains 12 Objects, i.e. at least(!) 48 bytes. 2 of them are Long objects. (Here you could save a bit if you used long instead of Long.) Hence your log objects alone would need around 100 bytes, give or take some, *without* the Map and *without* actual string data. This amounts to 10MB with 100K entries.

Comment: I ended up with around 450 byte per log item in my calculation above. That would mean approx 45MB for 100K entries. Still half of my heap, but at least in the same order of size. Could you put your calculations in your answer to make it a bit more useful?

Comment: According to http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/object_memory_usage.shtml, HotSpot uses 8 bytes per object, not 4, meaning 96 bytes, not 48. I still don't get your math when you go from 48 bytes to 100 bytes without adding data. Why do you double the amount?

Comment: You (and I) confuse the pointer (reference) size and the object size itself. If I have 48 bytes of pointers, then I will have with certainty another 48 bytes of objects, most likely more. To put it differently, you need at least 12 bytes for a *referenced* object. (Only overhead, no data).

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that each `String` object consumes space (24 bytes ?) for the actual `Object` definition, plus the reference to the char array, the offset (for `substring()` usage) etc. So representing a line as 'n' strings will add that additional storage requirement. Can you lazily evaluate these instead within your `LogEntry` class ?

(re. the String offset usage - prior to Java 7b6 `String.substring()` acts as a window onto an existing char array and consequently you need an offset. This has recently changed and it may be worth determining if a later JDK build is more memory efficient)

Comment: That is fine, but can you show me some math to show how that adds up to a tenfold increase?

Comment: By lazily evaluate, do you mean I would simply store the String entry in the LogEntry, and then parse the string when requested?

I am not sure how well that would work with Hibernate's demands of needing getters/setters, but I could easily get rid of Hibernate anyhow.

Comment: The getters/setters would do the calculation.

Comment: OK, fair enough. That will be fine for a refactoring later on ;-) Any idea how I would calculate approx how much memory is consumed by the current version? How many bytes for a Date, String, ArrayList, Map, etc

Comment: I suggest you google or search for "size of objects in java" and do the math yourself.

Comment: I could do that, but I still cannot get the number to match up with propertion of space increase. BTW an object takes up minimum 8 bytes, not 24 (ref: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/object_memory_usage.shtml)